# Read digital and analog input on Raspberry Pi 3 using Python

Tags: python, raspberry-pi

I have a sensor hooked up to the Raspberry Pi 3 right now, and I am currently trying to read the humidity and temperature sensor data. This sensor was previously hooked up to an Arduino, and I have successfully read the sensor values using the following **Arduino** code:

```c++
vout = analogRead(LM35DZ); //Reading temperature sensor data, LM35DZ = A1
tempc = (vout*500)/1023; //Temperature in Celsius 
readData = DHT.read22(dataPin); // Read humidity sensor data from Digital Port datapin = 8
t = DHT.temperature; // obtaining temperature for DHT sensor
h = DHT.humidity;
```

I am trying to achieve the same thing on the Raspberry Pi. I rehooked up all the wires and I am trying to get the same sensor data. My **dataPin** (previously pin 8 on Arduino) is connected to **GPIO17** and **LM35DZ**(previous connected to A1 on Arduino) is connected to **GPIO4**.

**I have two questions:**

1. How do you read analog data from a GPIO pin? I am looking for a similar functionality to Arduino's `analogRead()` function.
2. I am reading temperature and sensor data from GPIO17 using the following code:

   ```py
   import dht11
   import RPi.GPIO as GPIO           
   readData = dht11.DHT11(pin = 17)
   humidityResult = readData.read()
   t = humidityResult.temperature
   h = humidityResult.humidity
   ```

   But currently it's not reading any data (temperature and humidity give 0).

If anyone knows the solution to these two problems, please let me know!

Comment: Gpio pins do not read analog; only 1 and 0

Comment: https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=46839

Answer (score 0):

Cant do comments. (sorry)

Do you have an resistor between your power and dq pin? 
Might have an electrical technical drawing of your setup?

Comment: If you're talking about the temperature sensor, I do not. I connected it similar to this diagram on the Arduino: https://learn.sparkfun.com/tutorials/sik-experiment-guide-for-arduino---v32/experiment-7-reading-a-temperature-sensor and I kept the same configuration except changed the middle connection to GPIO4.

Comment: The problem that you are accounting is that the Raspberry Pi 3 doesn't have a analog input, you will not be able to use it directly on the ports. The solution could be to use a PWM module on the pins: pin12 GPIO18. But do not wire it without PWM.